# How to identify MongoDB collection name from MongoDB AWS EventBridge Trigger

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge, mongodb-stitch

I created 2 MongoDB triggers for 2 collections from one Mongo cluster and 1 trigger for a collection from another cluster. So altogether 3 triggers. I used AWS [Event Bridge to send trigger events to AWS](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/triggers/eventbridge/)

Here are the Event Bridges that were created as seen from the AWS console
[image]

My problem is **how do I identify to which collection and cluster each of these belong to**. For example if I had only 1 trigger in the list I would have known, but when I go on creating triggers for multiple collections is the problem

Does **`61d2ac6f624571ca88cfd71a`** in **`aws.partner/mongodb.com/stitch.trigger/61d2ac6f624571ca88cfd71a`** mean anything which can be used to identify the collection name.

[Mongo forum thread](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-identify-mongodb-collection-name-from-mongodb-aws-eventbridge-trigger/156323)

Answer (score 0):

The identifier "61d2ac6f624571ca88cfd71a" in the AWS Event Bridge rule ARN does not inherently provide information about the associated collection name or cluster. It appears to be a unique identifier for the specific trigger or rule.

To identify the collection and cluster associated with each trigger, you may need to adopt a naming convention or documentation strategy when creating triggers. Here are a few suggestions:

1- Naming Convention:

- When creating triggers, include the collection and cluster information in the rule name.
- Example: trigger_collection1_cluster1, trigger_collection2_cluster1, trigger_collection3_cluster2.

2- Metadata in Rule Description:

- When creating the rule, add metadata in the rule description that includes information about the associated collection and cluster.
- Example:
  yaml

Rule Name: Trigger1

Description: Collection: Collection1, Cluster: Cluster1

3- Use Tags:

- AWS resources support tagging. You can add custom tags to your Event Bridge rules, including information about the associated collection and cluster.
- Example:
  makefile

Tag: Collection=Collection1

Tag: Cluster=Cluster1

4- Documentation:

- Maintain a separate document or database that maps trigger identifiers to collections and clusters.
- Example:
  yaml

Trigger ID: 61d2ac6f624571ca88cfd71a

Collection: Collection1

Cluster: Cluster1

Choose the method that best fits your workflow and provides the necessary information for managing and identifying triggers in your setup. It's essential to establish a consistent and documented approach to avoid confusion as the number of triggers increases.